# Remove unused localisation strings from json files after comparing in dart files

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

I have used [easy_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) package in my flutter app to support multiple languages. So I have separate json files for *fr*, *de*, *mx*, *pt* languages. Now I want to remove unused strings from these json files after iterating through project files(dart files). Is there any script available for this?

Addition to this can we find out if only one file has localisation string added and other files are missing the same and which is used in the app.